# RxJava access item downstream

Tags: java, java-8, reactivex, rx-java2

I have chained a few `rx` operators together to do multiple tasks. I need to access a field from an object that is in the parent stream, downstream.

ie. How can I access `channel.uid` downstream?

```
createThing(panel) // Observable<~>
    .flatMapSingle(
            channel -> {
        return createOrUpdateItem(channel);
    })
    .flatMapCompletable(
            item -> {
        return linkItemToChannel(item.name, /* need access to channel.uid here */ channel.uid);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Observable.flatmap(Function mapper, BiFunction resultSelector)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)) (or [Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#flatMap(io.reactivex.functions.Function,%20io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction)) version). E.g.:

```
createThing(panel) //I assume that this method returns Observable
    .flatMap(channel -> createOrUpdateItem(channel).toObservable(),
            (channel, item) -> linkItemToChannel(item.name, channel.uid).toObservable())
    .toCompletable();
```

There is no similar overrided methods for `flatMapSingle` or `flatMapCompletable`, so you have to convert your `Single` and `Completable` to `Observable` (or `Flowable`). Or you can write your own operator ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @maxost's answer, here you can avoid the last `toCompletable()` and `toObservable()`:

```
createThing(panel)
.flatMap(new Function<Channel, ObservableSource<? extends Item>>() {
             @Override public ObservableSource<? extends Item> apply(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                 return createOrUpdateItem(channel).toObservable();
             }
         },
        new BiFunction<Channel, Item, Completable>() {
            @Override public Completable apply(Channel channel, Item item) throws Exception {
                return linkItemToChannel(item.name, channel.uid);
            }
        }
)
.ignoreElements() // converts to Completable
```

Lambda'd:

```
createThing(panel)
.flatMap(channel -> createOrUpdateItem(channel).toObservable(),
        (channel, item) -> linkItemToChannel(item.name, channel.uid))
.ignoreElements() // converts to Completable
```